# Probability Coupons

Tags: probability

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoDb7.jpg I don't understand why you alternate between adding and subtracting the probability. So you have the probability of the first coupon then you subtract the probability of the second coupon but add the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)
You add some possibilities, but some 'regions' in the Venn-diagrams (see link) are counted double, so you substract them. But then, you substract some regions to often, so you add them again...

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks. You you add the sum of the finite sets then subtract the double overlay then add in where they appear in three sets.

Answer (score 2):

We are looking for the probability of any of the events $P\left(\cup_{j=1}^N A_j\right)$.

At first you might say this is the sum of all probabilities for each event $p_1 = \sum_j P(A_j)$, but then you have counted the case where more than one event happens double, so we need to subtract those events.

The probability of more than one of the events $A_j$ can be viewed as $p_2 = \sum_{j_1 < j_2} P(A_{j_1}A_{j_2})$. But in **this** computation we are counting double all the terms where **three** events occur, so we must subtract that probability ($p_3$) from this one. As we were  already subtracting $p_2$ from $p_1$, when we subtract $p_3$ from $p_2$, this becomes an addition in the final sum.

Hope this helps.

Comment: good answer, this is called inclusion exclusion principle.